# login failed for user 'distributor_admin'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Distribution server to several Publications,
Today i started to get this error while i try to modify several Publication.

```
login failed for user 'distributor_admin'
```

It's important to highlight that i didn't change any password.
I wanted to know if anybody know what happen if i change the password in the administrative link ?
Dose it change me the pass to all replication so i don't have to change it manually one by one?
Is there any other way i cant change it without damaging\stopping all the other replications ? i don't want to create them all once again.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on replication
distributor properties
on the left side click on publishers
button of the page administrative link
You can change the password it will change it to every active replication you have.
Write it down.